# SSRS Export from Report Viewer mangles report (Excel, Word, PDF, etc)

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I am having a problem with a report export from the report viewer.

My report has two tablixes (?tabli?), each fed from same dataset.  One reports on the first half the row (first 4+3 columns), the other data from the 2nd half (first 4 and last 4 columns).

Report and column headers for the tablixes are different.  Works fine in report viewer.  On export to Word, PDF, XLS, etc, it loses it's d@mned mind.  Same column and report headers for both tabixes, drops a column from the 2nd tablix.

I created a 2nd data set, pointed at the same stored procedure, so each tablix would have it's own data source...no change.

On a lark, I dropped unused columns from each data source def, and FINALLY go the exports to mostly work.  Mostly.  Headers are not updating.

The report is grouped on a field in the Data Set.  I hide the text box containing the field, and do a row in the header does a DS lookup based on the value in the text box.  Again, works great in report viewer, but loses it's $#! when exported.  WHEN KEYS CHANGE ON PAGE BREAK, it never does another data lookup.

Tried a 2nd look up data set, and that didn't fix it either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to know where to start (for me at least) without seeing the report design and a sample of the output from both the 'live' report and the exported version. I have had issues with labels not getting updated correctly between two objects (charts and tables) which I had to concede was just a bug in SSRS that's been there for years. If it looks to be the same thing, I'll see if I can find how I worked around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a fix, but a work around.

I had a dynamic header row in the two tablixes (tabli?) that I was doing a lookup to fill on each page break.  As said, worked fine in reportviewer, but choked on export.

I finally moved the lookup to a text box in page header, and was able to export with updated info on each page.